# Python sqlite write operations

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlite

In a desktop python application (Python version 3.6) I use a sqlite database.
If I run the application by IDE (Eclipse) the write operations are fast, when I run application in Windows with command line "python file.py" the write operations are slower.
Because I have this behavior and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: How much of a discrepancy do you see in performance?  What about selects, are they are much slower running from the application directly?

Comment: Are you running the same Python version, and the same copy of Python, in the IDE and on the command line?

Comment: I don't observe discrepancy in SELECT, only INSERT and UPDATE. In Windows the application freeze for a while, 0.5-1 second, in Eclipse doesn't